# How to load a chart from Kendo UI on the click of a button

Tags: javascript, html, kendo-ui, kendo-dataviz

I am using a Kendo UI dataviz bar chart. Currently the graph loads when the page loads. How do i change it to load on a button click instead?

The code is shown on the site,
http://demos.kendoui.com/dataviz/bar-charts/local-data.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger it off a button click with relative ease using jQuery. Here's a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/latenightcoder/6jyKT/1

You might want to go through a tutorial on jQuery basics in case other such similar questions come up. I've listed one such tutorial here: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery